# Maximum sum by splitting given string

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, divide-and-conquer

Given a string S consisting of only digits. We need to divide the string into 4 integers such that their sum is maximum. How this can be solved ? Please help

**Note : Each integer should be ≤ 10^12 and should not contain any leading zeroes.**

Also size of each string can be almost 20.

Example : Let S=52310 then answer is 56 as 4 integers are 52,3,1,0. So maximum sum is 56 (52 + 3 + 1 + 0).

How this can be done efficiently as I don't want to go for brute solution because of its high complexity as splitting at each available 4 positions will lead to a very ineffective approach.

Comment: Perhaps this article is relevant: [open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: @BrianTompsett This looks like homework ? I didnt knew that. Which institute gives such problems for home assignments

Comment: If each integer is <= 10^12 then the maximum size of each substring shall be 13. How are you saying it can be up to 20?

Comment: Since the maximum string length is `13 * 4 = 52`, a brute force attempt will be quite efficient. I wrote a little, inefficient (lots of string manipulations) Python script, and I still solves the problem in no time.

Answer (score -1):

Try this , but in java

```
    private void method()
{
    String value = "52310";
    String sortedString ;
    int stringLength;
    long total = 0; 

    char[] arr = value.toCharArray();
    List<String> seperatedIntegers = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(arr.length > 3)
    {
        sortedString = sort(arr);
        stringLength = sortedString.length();

        for(int m = 0 ; m < 3 ; m ++)
        {
            seperatedIntegers.add(sortedString.substring(stringLength - 1, stringLength));          
            stringLength--;
        }

        seperatedIntegers.add(sortedString.substring(0, stringLength));                 
    }



    if(seperatedIntegers.size() > 0)
    {
        for(int n = 0 ; n < seperatedIntegers.size() ; n ++)
        {
            total = total + Long.valueOf(seperatedIntegers.get(n)); 
        }   
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(total), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

private String sort(char[] arr)
{
    int temp;
    String val = "";

    List<Integer> sortedValues  = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i ++)
    {
        sortedValues.add(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(arr[i])));
    }


    for(int j = 1; j < sortedValues.size();  j++)
    {
        for(int k = j; k > 0; k--)
        {
            if(sortedValues.get(k) > sortedValues.get(k-1))
            {
                temp=sortedValues.get(k);
                sortedValues.set(k, sortedValues.get(k-1));
                sortedValues.set(k - 1, temp);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int l = 0; l < sortedValues.size() ; l ++)
    {
        val = val + String.valueOf(sortedValues.get(l));
    }

    return val;     
}
```

Comment: Be kind enough to mention the reason if someone down voting the answer , it would help people to identify what is the mistake that has been done . Not ethical at all. Just down voting means, down voter helps to keep the mistake forever, not to solve it.